# How to migrate from transport client to rest high level client elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I need to upgrade my code from transport client to rest high level client, but i faced a problem of transforming configuration.

I found this https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/7.3/_changing_the_client_8217_s_initialization_code.html .
But this manual doesnt help me with adding settings and plugin to the client.

```
Settings settings = Settings.builder()
        .put("client.transport.ignore_cluster_name",true)
        .put("some_other_settings","value")
        .addPlugin(SSLSearchGuardPlugin.class)
   .build();

TransportClient transportClient = new PreBuiltTransportClient(settings)
        .addTransportAddress(new 
TransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 9300))
```

Comment: did you find the answer? I am stuck in this problem for my work!!